# Using slideUp() and slideDown() functions based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used a code to toggle a panel in my html page whenever I click a particular element on my html page( which is a blank hyperlink in my case within  tag ):

```
    <script> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#technology").click(function(e){
        $("#technology_panel").slideToggle("slow");
        e.preventDefault()
        });
     });
    </script>
```

This is working fine as long as I simply want to toggle the panel up/down. But what I actually want 
is when I click on the particular element, the panel comes down, but when I click anywhere else on the html page the panel should go up.I tried this code but this doesn't work as expected:

```
    if (document.getElementById(planning).click()== true)
    { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#planning").click(function(e){
         $("#planning_panel").slideDown("slow");
         e.preventDefault()
      });
    });
    }
     else
     {
         $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#planning").click(function(e){
                $("#planning_panel").slideUp("slow");
             e.preventDefault()
             });
           });
     }
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` must be a very first when function body starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the click event to the document and use the logic based on the element clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $panel = $("#planning_panel");
        if (e.target.id === 'planning') {
            $panel.slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $panel.slideUp('slow');
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: @Sushanth--This code still has problem. I will explain what exactly I have in my html page. I have defined a hyperlink like this:

`<a href="" style="position:relative; left:-65px" 
id="planning">PLANNING</a>`

The idea is `1. when I click on `Planning` the panel must slidedown and when I click again it slides up.` `2.Also along with this if I click anywhere on the document, then the panel should slide up if its already down.` `Point 2.` is working fine but `point 1` is not working at all.

Comment: @Sushanth--The issue is solved. I only changed this line of your code:

`if (e.target.id === 'planning') {
            $panel.slideDown('slow');
        }` to `if (e.target.id === 'planning') {
            $panel.slideToggle('slow');
        }`

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#planning").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var $panel = jQuery("#planning_panel");
        if ($this.is(':hidden')) {
            $panel.slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $panel.slideUp('slow');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's not() function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#planning").click(function(e){
         $("#planning_panel").slideDown("slow");
   });

   $("#planning").not().click(function(e){
         $("#planning_panel").slideUp("slow");
   });
});
```